# Using form_for with multiple models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, models

My apologies if this has been asked before, but I'm not sure about this.

I would like to know if it's possible to use a form in Rails with multiple models.

I know you can do something like this

```
<%= form_for @users do |f| %>
```

In the form, I'm trying to create, I need form fields for 2 different models, because I need to use the attributes from the other model.

I was thinking something like this might work

```
<%= form_for @users, @songs do |f,g| %>

  <%= f.label :username %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>

  <%= g.label :song %>
  <%= g.text_field :song %>

<% end %>
```

I believe this will work, but I'm not sure. Is this possible in Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for rails built-in helper `fields_for`.

See the docs [here](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for).